Mqttx Connecting to MQTT Broker...failed with state -2
I am trying to connect to a mosquitto server on my local computer using an ESP32. I have already installed mosquitto, it is running and a local MQTTX client was able to connect to it but my ESP32 is not able to connect to it. I have entered the same details as in MQTTX.
The code running on the ESP32:
#include <WiFi.h> // WiFi library for ESP32 
#include <PubSubClient.h> // Connect and publish data to the MQTT broker 
// WiFi credentials 
const char* ssid = "<redacted>"; 
const char* wifi_password = "<redacted>"; 
// MQTT credentials 
const char* mqtt_server = "127.0.0.1"; // Replace with your MQTT broker IP 
const char* control_topic = "test/esp32/led"; 
const char* hello_topic = "test/esp32/hello"; 
const char* mqtt_username = "<redacted>"; // MQTT username 
const char* mqtt_password = "<redacted>"; // MQTT password 
const char* clientID = "mqttx_bc0ba190";

#define LED_PIN 12

WiFiClient wifiClient;
PubSubClient client(wifiClient);

void setup_wifi() {
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  
  // Connect to the WiFi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, wifi_password);
}




#include <WiFi.h>            // WiFi library for ESP32
#include <PubSubClient.h>    // Connect and publish data to the MQTT broker
// WiFi credentials
const char* ssid = "RD 6114";
const char* wifi_password = "n0832>N1";
// MQTT credentials
const char* mqtt_server = "127.0.0.1"; // Replace with your MQTT broker IP
const char* control_topic = "test/esp32/led";
const char* hello_topic = "test/esp32/hello";
const char* mqtt_username = "aksa"; // MQTT username
const char* mqtt_password = "Aksa@1234";  // MQTT password
const char* clientID = "mqttx_bc0ba190";

Please do not post images of code, post the text in the quesion and user the toolbar to format it. Images are hard read, impossible for user that need screen readers and un searchable.  Also please do not add code as comments, use the Edit link under the question

You are trying to connect to a MQTT broker on the IP 127.0.0.1 which is the Loopback address. This means your ESP32 is trying to connect to itself and therefore fails to connect.
Your mosquitto broker is apparently running on the same host as your MQTTx client, that is why the Loopback address worked there.
If you simply want to test MQTT connection, there are some public MQTT brokers available you can connect to. If you need to connect to your local mosquitto broker, you need to find out the IP address it is running on and make sure you can connect to it (e.g. same local network) before putting the IP instead of 127.0.0.1.

can you elaborate further how can i find the ip address

@AbdullahSaleh That really depends on your operating system. On macOS and most Linux distributions you can open a shell and use the ifconfig command, on Windows you can open PowerShell and use the Get-NetIPAddress cmdlet.
